# Cupy error: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'gradient'

Tags: cupy

I'm a bit new to GPU programming, but I saw on the Cupy documentation that cupy.gradient exists as a function, but whenever I try using it, I get the following error - `AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'gradient'`. Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm using it incorrectly, but would love to know if someone else is having this issue too. Is there a different way to calculate the gradient using Cupy?

Comment: Hi! welcome to st. have you checked your Cupy version? apparently 'gradient' is relatively new (from v9.0.0)

Comment: Ah it seems that I am using v8.0.0 so that would explain the error thanks! Is there any CUDA requirement for Cupy v9.0.0 or can it just be updated through 'pip install -U cupy'

Comment: CuPy v9 supports CUDA 9.2 or later. You can use `cupy-cudaXXX` package instead of `cupy` so that you don't have to build from source. https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html#installing-cupy